# Css and/or html difficulty

Tags: html, css, width

I just installed a plug-in on my webshop and the css got somehow weird..

If you look on: solved

The breadcrumb is not full width just like at: solved

What am i missing in my code or css?

Thanks

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.osolemio-almere.nl%2Findex.php%3Froute%3Dnews%2Fnews%26news_id%3D2&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Because it is inside the `#content` div, which has a `padding-left: 40px;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<div id='content'>` has its `padding-left` and `padding-right` set to 40px.

You should move `<div class="breadcrumb">` out of `content`, so that it is a child of `<div id="container">`.

But first, you should install [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and learn to solve these problems yourself. It is very simple.

Answer (score 2):

You've put the div with class breadcrumbs inside the div with class content. It should go outside.
You should have compared both generated htmls and see the differences (in relevant places). That's a good step in finding it out yourself.